# Spring upload file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm a novice in Spring, i started to develop an application to upload files,i used the official spring documentation but, i have this error:

```
Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:823)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:143)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:191)
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:350)
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
 at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:155)
 at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:138)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:907)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:750)
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring's file-upload stuff uses [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) under the covers. You'll need to download that and include it in your app. This, in turn, also requires [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), so youi'll need that also.

Answer (score 0):

you missed to add jar "common file upload" or "file io" or added older verson of jar

good example of file upload is http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-upload-file-ajax-jquery-formdata/

thank you
umesh sohaliya